# Multiple columns and sorting

Tags: mysql, max

I have tried for several hours now to get my SQL query to sort by price. Here we go:

Table `INFO`

```
id (unique id)
mid (some id)
name
```

Table `PRICES`

```
id (some unique id)
fuid (id for showing wich entry from INFO this price is connected to)
dated (date)
```

SQL Query:

```
select INFO.id, INFO.mid, INFO.name, PRICES.price, PRICES.dated
from INFO, PRICES
WHERE INFO.id = PRICES.fuid
ORDER BY PRICES.dated asc
limit 100
```

The result I want is a list of all entries in `INFO` with the latest price from `PRICES`. Only the latest price, one price per `INFO` entry.

What I get: I get a list of unique entries from `INFO` but I get the first price entered in the `PRICES`, not the latest.

I cant get `max()` to help me sort the prices column. Anybody who knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `GROUP BY` with `MAX()`? The following use of `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` would probably do what you need:

```
select INFO.id, INFO.mid, INFO.name, PRICES.price, MAX(PRICES.dated) 
from INFO, PRICES 
where INFO.id = PRICES.fuid
group by INFO.id, INFO.mid, INFO.name, PRICES.price
order by INFO.name asc 
limit 100
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` column(s) can be anything you want; it doesn't have to be `MAX(PRICES.dated)`.

**EDIT**: I see what you mean. You could use a temporary table like this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce1cb/2).

Comment: Sorry, did post wrong SQL Query. My Query was supposed to be: select INFO.id, INFO.mid, INFO.name, PRICES.price, PRICES.dated from INFO, PRICES WHERE INFO.id = PRICES.fuid GROUP BY INFO.id ORDER BY PRICES.dated asc limit 100. With this GROUP BY I get only one hit per entry in the INFO table. With your query, kensnyder, I get a lot of rows with all prices from the PRICES column. I want only one entry per INFO row...